# How to take photo via camera element and attach it in Form correctly?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, attachment, powerapps

I want to take a picture via Camera, don't save it on device and when the form is done, user submits the form and picture should by succesfully sent to sharepoint list.

I have tried two ways:
x sending picture to column of Image type (image, not hyperlink) and it didn't work any way.
x sending picture to column of Attachment type, and I have really big hope with this one.

The way I do it:

Camera: *OnSelect = Set(photoValue; Camera2.Photo);; ClearCollect(photo; {Name:"urzadzenie.png"; Value:Camera2.Photo})*

1. I take picture via Camera. I take it by clicking on it and I display it below camera via Image element. I collect photo with some attributes. Photo is successfully shown.
2. The attachment element: *Items = photo* and after taking a picture, there is added file with "urzadzenie.png" as name in the attachment field

But when submitting the form, below the attachment filed it says:

**Id field is required** (translating to english)

When I add *Id* attribute in (1.) in ClearCollect and set it to any value (example 0, 1 , "nothing"), the form is being submitted WITHOUT the attachment neither the photo in Image column. What value should Id has to make it work??

All I want to do is send photo to Sharepoint list without saving it anywhere else, only in the list, is there a way to do this? If I have to save it on Sharepoint in some kind of folder and then refer to it in Image column or Attachment column in my particular Sharepoint List, how do I do that?

I also thought about sth like clicking "Add the attachment", then select "take photo" and that's all, but the I need to delete other option than "Take photo" and that would by lovely, but how to do that?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will have a solution for your issue
[Link](https://explore.emtecinc.com/blog/how-to-upload-camera-pictures-directly-to-microsoft-sharepoint-with-powerapps-and-microsoft-flow)